# Passing in the key and returning the object javascript

Tags: javascript, json

With a JSON array structured like this one,

```
"object1": {
  "key1": "value1"
  "key2": "value2"
}
"object2": {
  "key3": null
  "key4": null
}
}
```

Could I pass in the key eg. key3 and get returned the object it is part of eg. object2?

I know this would be possible with a for loop, but I have a lot of keys so I am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: In java there is something called for each loop or enhanced for loop. As JS is similar to Java I'm sure it exists if you look up JS enhanced for loop

Comment: The question is quite unclear, as the JSON structure you gave does not look to me like a JSON array. Can you please provide the exact data structure you're trying to work with?

Comment: "**I know this would be possible with a for loop**", then what is your problem? Time complexity? Sure the compiled code may be faster but is really putting a for loop that much? Have you profiled and the results weren't good?

Comment: I am looking for something that does not require iterating over keys because I have over 4k+ keys and this code is going to be run on a mobile phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all of the keys and create a lookup table. This would allow searching in `O(1)` after incurring the preprocessing cost.

```js
const obj = {
  "object1": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "object2": {
    "key3": null,
    "key4": null
  }
};
const lookup = {};
for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
  for (const k2 of Object.keys(obj[k])) {
    lookup[k2] = k;
  }
}
console.log(lookup['key3']);
console.log(obj[lookup['key3']]);
console.log(lookup['key1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = {
  "object1": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "object2": {
    "key3": null,
    "key4": null
  }
};
let keyToLookFor = "key3";
Object.entries(json).forEach(([key,entry]) => { 
  if(Object.keys(entry).includes(keyToLookFor)) { 
    console.log(json[key]) 
  } 
})
```